# Does a magnetic field have gravity?

Tags: gravity, electromagnetic-radiation

Re-reading https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/33156/5265; I find myself thinking if light, being EM in the humanly visible spectrum, may possess gravity -  does a magnetic field also possess gravity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Electromagnetic_stress-energy_tensor), the electromagnetic tensor $F^{\mu \nu}$ contributes to the stress energy tensor $T^{\mu \nu}$ by

$$T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{\mu_0} \left(F^{\mu \alpha} g_{\alpha \beta} F^{\nu \beta} - \frac{1}{4} g^{\mu \nu} F^{\gamma \delta} F_{\gamma \delta} \right)$$

The Einstein equations govern how the stress-energy tensor is coupled to spacetime curvature.  Since the magnetic field is entirely captured by the electromagnetic tensor, the answer is *yes*, magnetic fields contribute to gravitation.